# Will the data files be lost when I update my game apk in play store?

Tags: python, android, kivy

First things first, I'm very new to devloping android applications and games, so please bare with my poor knowledge of things. Thanks!

So I'm developing a game in kivy, where the data such as money, items, level are started in a seperate py file. Essentially, there is a `main.py` and a `data.py`. Now if/when I update my game on play store, will it lose the `data.py`, causing it to reset everything? If yes, how should I overcome it? Thanks a ton in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you are storing the data in a python file? I would recommend against this, and would instead suggest you store the data in something like a json or CSV. The python file will be overwritten if you update the app, however if you use a file saved externally on the device it will not.